# Iterating through objects in Handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I have a JavaScript object that looks like this:

```
{
    "key1": {
        name: "SomeName1"
    },
    "key2": {
        name: "SomeName2"
    },
    "key3": {
        name: "SomeName3"
    }
}
```

I am passing this into my handlebars template. I want to display all the names on the screen.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
        data: myObject
    });
});
```

In my index.hbs file, I have:

```
{{#each data}}
    Name: {{this.name}}
    <br>
{{/each}}
```

For now, its just displaying

```
Name:
Name:
Name:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your code to work your object needs to look something like this

```
{
  data:[
    { name: '1'},
    { name: '2'},
    { name: '3'}
  ]
}
```

or literate through object keys like this

```
{{#each this}}
   {{#each this}}
         Name: {{this}}
         <br>
   {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: I tried the second option, but it just shows my keys as incremental numbers starting from 1

Comment: I was trying to make u understand how it works instead of just giving u the answer. but if still u don't understand please see this  http://jsfiddle.net/gV7YZ/121/ . I'm sure this is more clear